# Linux: быстрая вставка теста

Tags: linux, pycharm

Есть ли какой то софт, чтобы сделать быструю вставку теста. Например прикрепил я к комбинации клавиш 'ctrl+v+b' текст 'hello word', и в любой момент могу вставить этот текст.

Comment: тест нужно запомнить, и не зависимости что в буфере обмена, или даже не в зависимости от сессии вставлять текст который храниться в памяти(пример 'hello word').

Comment: Нет, и на мой взляд, вне конкретного приложения это абсолютно бессмысленно.

А вот внутри приложения -- зависит от него. Например,  в `emacs` это реализовано. Вы можете легко написать макрос (допустим, выводящий в текущий буфер константный текст), а потом привязать его выполнение к комбинации клавиш.

Comment: а pycharm есть такая возможность?

Answer (score 2):

Я для похожей задачи использую xvkbd. Команда:

```
xvkbd -xsendevent FILENAME
```

отправляет содержимое FILENAME в текущее активное окно. В качестве FILENAME можно использовать -, тогда ввод берется из stdin. В вашем случае нужно что-то вроде:

```
echo "Hello, world!" | xvkbd -xsendevent -
```

Вешаете эту команду на нужную комбинацию и все. Это делается где-то в настройках Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Прикрепляйте правильно к комбинации `ctrl+c` и вставляйте правильно комбинацией `ctrl+v`.

**UPD**

Что косается pyCharm то это одна из IDE семейства ItelijIDEA от JetBrains, в которой есть история буфера обмена и можно вызвать вставку при сочетании: `ctrl(cmd)+shift+v`. Поскольку это одно семейство то оно поддерживает также теже самые плагины (ну или большенство) от ItelliJIDEA, но чтоб они решали именно такую узкую задачу я не нашел, нашел только следующее:

[IdeaVIM](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164?pr=idea), [Emacs](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7163?pr=idea) - из пушки по воробьям, но очень мощные инструменты, просто не истово просто хрендец...
Можете сами поискать нужные плагины Preferences>Plugins

я emacs не знаю, а в vim есть регистры - своего рода именнованные буфера.

vim example:

```
[Visual mode] выбираем нужный текст (V<Left>/<Right>),
("ky) - " указатель регистра, k - регистр, y -Yunk/copy выделенное в регистр k
[Command mode] чтобы вставить информацию из регистра используют следующее: ("kp) - " указатель регистра, k - регистрб, p - вставка информации из регистра.
```

Answer (score 1):

Последний выделенный фрагмент текста можно вставлять кликом по колесику мышки

Comment: у меня kubuntu и это работает. но все же данная фича, имхо, зависит от среды рабочего стола.

Comment: эта фича - это особенность X.org. и она известна уже очень давно. Правда, в Wayland могли и сломать ( с классической отмазкой - пользователи нажимают и пугаются)

Answer (score 1):

можно определить *compose*-последовательность <kbd>compose key</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd>.

подробнее смотрите в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424263/178576).