# Как сделать ключевые слова на клавишах как в Spectrum?

Tags: linux, gui, desktop, клавиатура

Раньше был компьютер Spectrum,и там был 

специальный режим набора, когда клавиша печатала сразу целое слово.

Например, нажал клавишу <kbd>P</kbd>, а напечаталось слово PRINT

Как сделать такой режим в Linux сразу во всех программах, то есть на уровне системы, а не отдельного приложения?

Видел, что в xkb есть некие actions (в compatibility map), но в списке доступных я не нашел замены одной клавиши на последовательность нажатий.

Будет ли хорошим решением добавить новую разновидность action, или есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 4):

можно воспользоваться механизмом `xcompose`, предварительно определив в настройках клавиатуры клавишу, используемую в качестве <kbd>compose key</kbd>.

пример файла `~/.XCompose`:

```
<Multi_key> <P> : "PRINT"
```

нажимаете и отпускаете <kbd>compose key</kbd>, затем <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, и получаете слово *PRINT*.

примеры правил можно посмотреть в `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`

Comment: так и напрашивается [Compose](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose)

Comment: да, это вариант. Я правда хотел, чтобы работало как "режим" - в одно касание (просто нажать кнопку), а не в два (сначала <key>compose key</key> а потом кнопку).

Comment: @hse5yzdx , так уберите `<Multi_key>` из примера. только после этого ввести символ `P` будет «сложновато».

Comment: ничего-ничего, у меня кроме P много других кнопок. Это я для примера её написал.