# Вставка буквы по нажатию клавши

Tags: linux, xubuntu

Дистрибутив: Xubuntu 14.04
Ядро: 3.19
Разрядность: i686

Есть старый ноут, на нём не работает латинская "t". Можно ли по нажатию, например, Alt + F3 в активное поле ввода вставлять "t" или, лучше, эмулировать нажатие этой клавиши без учёта раскладки?
Onboard не очень удобна

Comment: можно, например, воспользоваться механизмом [xcompose](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/424221/178576).

Comment: Интересно, как на ноуте эмулируется цифровая клавиатура, которая справа на обычных. Потому как в linux как и в windows работает ввод кодов символов с клавиатуры. Alt+84 T, Alt+116 t. Комбинация вводится не отпуская Alt с цифровой клавиатуры :)

Comment: или починить клавиатуру

Answer (score -1):

xmodmap

не знаю работает ли на xubuntu, но можешь попробовать

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.