# Автозамена текста по шаблону в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

На windows часто использую удобнейшую функцию программы PuntoSwitcher для автозамены введённого текста на заданный шаблон. Например, ввожу `д_у` и после пробела текст заменяется на `Доброго утра!`. Есть ли программа, реализующая подобный функционал под Ubuntu?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону Xneur.

Comment: Я не нашёл в данном приложении такого функционала. Если там есть подобное - прошу пояснить как это настроить.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не дочитал. Увидел только "аналог PuntoSwitcher". Возможно, для ваших целей можно настроить https://autohotkey.com/, но это будет не просто

Comment: Цитирую главную страницу "AutoHotkey is a free, open-source scripting language for Windows". Хотя Вы правы. Нечто подобное есть в виде пакета AutoKey. Благодарю за наводку!

Comment: Премного благодарен @Chubatiy! AutoKey ну практически то, что надо!

Comment: Не за что. Удачи!

Comment: программа есть. причём не в одном дистрибутиве одной операционной системы, а в целой куче операционных систем. и вы ей в данный момент **уже** пользуетесь. называется *xorg*. [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/424263/178576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях дали наводку на пакет **AutoKey**. Пакет решает мою проблему. Устанавливается из стандартного репозитория командой `sudo apt-get install autokey-gtk`. Поддерживает скрипты на Python.

Answer (score 1):

для реализации такой простой задачи вообще ничего устанавливать не надо. всё уже есть и работает. программа называется *xorg*. а у неё (помимо многого прочего) есть такая штука, как [xcompose](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose) (см., например, вопросы здесь, касающиеся xcompose — их [немного](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=xcompose)).

единственное «неудобство»: чтобы вы всё-таки смогли вводить букву <kbd>д</kbd>, надо будет перед требуемой последовательностью нажимать (и сразу отпускать) т.н. *compose key* (какая это будет клавиша — вы определяете сами в настройках клавиатуры).

после этого добавьте в `~/.XCompose` такую например строку:

```
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_de> <underscore> <Cyrillic_u>: "доброе утро"
```

хотя имеет смысл сократить до букв, убрав подчёркивание (*underscore*):

```
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_de> <Cyrillic_u>: "доброе утро"
```

---

теперь, нажав (и отпустив) назначенную вами в качестве *compose key* клавишу, а затем введя последовательно <kbd>ду</kbd>, вы получите строку "доброе утро".

---

если строка не вводится (но вводится единичный символ, подставленный вместо строки), обратите внимание на этот вопрос: [подставляется только единичный символ, а строка игнорируется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/826437/178576)

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ! Обязательно попробую.