# подставляется только единичный символ, а строка игнорируется

Tags: xorg, xcompose

настраиваю [xcompose](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose) и столкнулся со странным поведением.

если добавить в `~/.XCompose` строку

```
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_de>: "1"
```

то «всё работает»: после нажатия (и отпускания) *compose key* с последующим вводом буквы <kbd>д</kbd> вводится символ <kbd>1</kbd>.

а если заменить строку на такую (добавлен один символ в подстановочную строку):

```
<Multi_key> <Cyrillic_de>: "11"
```

то после нажатия *compose key* и затем <kbd>д</kbd> ничего не вводится, а раздаётся сигнал, как-будто такой *compose*-последовательности вообще нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если ввод осуществляется в окно, использующее [*gtk*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK%2B), то надо сменить умолчальный модуль [метода ввода](https://blogs.gnome.org/happyaron/2011/01/15/linux-input-method-brief-summary/) (*input method*, сокращённо *im*).

например, вполне работоспособен со строками длиннее одного символа модуль *xim*.

имя метода передаётся x-клиентам, использующим *gtk*, через переменную окружения `GTK_IM_MODULE`. чтобы её получили все x-клиенты, лучше присваивать ей значение где-нибудь при старте x-сессии.

обычно это проще всего сделать через ресурсный файл x-сессии, который по умолчанию называется `~/.xsessionrc`.

добавьте в него строку:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

и перезапустите x-сессию.

---

#### дополнение:

для программ, использующих [*qt*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt), надо [пере]определять переменную `QT_IM_MODULE`:

```
export QT_IM_MODULE="xim"
```